# Cart page content in simple block in ubercart 3

Tags: ubercart

Can i use http://www.mysite.com/cart page content in simple block using ubercart 3 in drupal 7? I want same http://www.mysite.com/cart page content area ("cart form") in a simple block for show cart content in any region to authenticated user.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is a module [Ubercart pictured cart block](http://drupal.org/project/uc_pic_cart_block) which will display the content of the cart page into a block. It will provide all functionality which are cart page. You can set the block in a region from block administration page in admin.